# SQL DELETE group of records based on opposite group being empty

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

In table T, I'm trying to delete all records in a groups having same value of A, but only if all members of this group have B set to 'x'.

Given the Table T:

```
+-------+--------+
|   A   |   B    |
+-------+--------+
|    2  |   ''   |
|    2  |   'x'  |
|    2  |   ''   |
|    8  |   'x'  |
|    8  |   'x'  |
|   15  |   ''   |
|   15  |   ''   |
+-------+--------+
```

The two records with A == 8 have to be deleted as all two of them have B==1. The group of A==2 has mixed value of B so it stays. And group of A==15 doesn't have all of it's B equal to 1 it also stays.

Is this possible to do by one query?

If not, any other way that is fast enough for a table with a lot of records?

Comment: Yes possible to do in one query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try this query:

```
delete from T
where A in (
select A
from T
group by A
having sum(B) = count(*)
)
```

if column b can contain non 0/1 values, you can add additional conditions:

`having sum(B) = count(*) and min(b)=1 and max(b)=1`

if you can't use numeric values, you can just use min/max, like

`having min(b)='x' and max(b)='x'`

Comment: Thanks! this works great, but B is not numeric in my case. I corrected the question. sorry for confusion

Comment: Thank you! works fine. You think @NoDisplayName 's answer  with Case clause will be faster than this?

Comment: @sny I suppose it will be the same

Comment: Thanks for quick responses. Both answers, this and @NoDisplayName, do the job! Will mark the answer that came first.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. `Group by and Having` with some aggregate should work

```
DELETE FROM tablename
WHERE  a IN(SELECT a
            FROM   tablename
            GROUP  BY a
            HAVING count(case when b='x' then 1 end) = Count(b)
```